# Как перебрать массив из нескольких значений?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть массив из нескольких значений нужно его перебрать и добавить в бд.
Получается так:
Использую api яндекс карт, в поиске ищу адрес, получаю полный адрес(Россия, город, улица, дом) и координаты долгота и широта.

До этого я перебирал массив только из полного адреса и отправлял в бд как отдельные записи с уникальным id.
Сейчас мне нужно добавить к этим адресам еще и координаты(долготу и широту). Добавляется только одна и та же, потому что не правильно перебираю массив. Подскажите как можно сделать, не получается.

```html
$address = $_POST['address'];
$coordinates = $_POST['coordinates'];
$coordinates2 = $_POST['coordinates2'];
foreach ($address as $key => $address) {
    $query->execute([:name' => $address, ':coordinates' => $coordinates,':coordinates2' => $coordinates2]);
}
```

Чтобы получилось (примерно):

```
id | Полный адрес        | долгота  | широта
2  | Россия, Москва и тд | 55.45465 | 43.465465
```

Comment: покажи хоть данные которые перебираешь, не понятно структура.

Comment: $coordinates[$key]